# Memory Mapped File VS Named Pipe - C#

Tags: c#, named-pipes, memory-mapped-files

In this Article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/salvapatuel/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4/

It exclaims that:

> The memory mapped file is the most efficient way for multiple processes on a single machine to communicate with each other.

If this statement is valid, then what exactly is the difference between using a MMF for inter-process comms and using a Named Pipe?

Comment: The advantage of named pipes is their ease-of-use, but MMF is faster. Also, named pipes can be used Intermachine, whereas MMF is only intramachine.

Comment: One of the differences is, Named pipes support a server / client scenario, while MMF does not.

Comment: It is rarely "most efficient" when you add everything you need to make an MMF useful.  It is a very raw primitive and you always need to add synchronization to ensure that you only ever read data that was written.  Also pretty hard to take advantage of in C#, it is only truly efficient when you use pointers so you can directly read or write from/to the mapped memory.   Most tutorials will get you to use a stream.  A named pipe also uses an MMF to exchange data, except that it is hidden inside the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named Pipe is used for short message between 2 or more processess, and in my experience, it's slow.

If you want to share much data then the use of MMF is correct.